# How to speedup git clone for big binary files (disable delta compression)

Tags: git, compression, binaryfiles, git-clone

**Question**

I was wondering why `git clone` seems to not respect `-delta` in `.gitattributes`.

**Reproduction**

I prepared a test repository with:

- `.gitattributes` containing  `*.bin binary -delta`
- 10 commits with a 10 MB random binary file

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup repository
git init --quiet repo
cd repo

echo '*.bin binary -delta' > .gitattributes
git add .gitattributes
git commit --quiet -m 'attributes'

for i in $(seq 10); do
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=data.bin bs=1MB count=10 status=none
    git add data.bin
    git commit --quiet -m "data $i"
done
cd ..

# create clone repository
time git clone --no-local repo clone

# repack original repository
cd repo
time git repack -a -d
```

Output:

```
Cloning into 'clone'...
remote: Counting objects: 33, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
remote: Total 33 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (33/33), 95.40 MiB | 19.94 MiB/s, done.

real    0m25,085s
user    0m22,749s
sys     0m0,948s

Counting objects: 33, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Total 33 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

real    0m5,652s
user    0m4,173s
sys     0m0,178s
```

**Observations**

*time*

- Cloning: `clone` takes **always 25s**
- Optimizing: `repack` takes **25s with** and **5s without** delta compression

*compressed objects*

- Cloning: `clone` compresses **always 31 objects**
- Optimizing: `repack` compresses **31 objects with** and **21 objects without** delta compression

**Expectations**

Both operations (`repack` and `clone`) are using `pack-objects`.

Therefore my expectation is that `clone` should respect `-delta` and be about as fast as `repack`.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong answer (my excuse: heavy pain meds for kidney stone :-) ). I note that if you pack the source repository *first*, the clone goes quickly. I'm not sure what's going on, even after inserting some debug into the Git source, but it looks like loose objects get packed, ignoring the directives, when cloning.

Answer (score 2):

The `clone` command doesn't respect the in-repo `.gitattributes` file regarding delta compression.

The solution is to place `.git/info/attributes` on the server side.

For more details see the [original answer](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=153197844224467) from Jeff King.